# What role(s) does Statistical Computing / Computational Statistics play in Clinical Trials?

Tags: biostatistics, clinical-trials, computational-statistics, phd

I am going to pursue a PhD in Statistics, and the two fields that I am really interested are Statistical Computing / Computational Statistics and Clinical Trials (mainly because I like doing Statistical Computing on R, and also I am interested in helping those people who are in need for medical treatment).

Is it possible to do a research that combines Statistical Computing with Clinical Trials? If yes, what are the examples of the Statistical research that has been done that relates Statistical Computing with Clinical Trials? I don't know if such is possible, because I know very little about Clinical Trials or its relationship with Statistical Computing, if there is any.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

In general, the goal of a clinical trial design is to plan the trial so as to eliminate or vastly reduce the likelihood of bias and confounding. In doing so, clinical trials can usually be analyzed with relatively simple statistical models. While I have little understanding of computational statistics, it is clear to me that the design of trials, not their analysis, remains the largest challenge in the field of clinical trials.